# How to pass authorization token from react to spring boot

Tags: reactjs, spring-boot, authentication

I want to pass one Authentication token from reactjs(front end) to the springboot(backend) application.
I have already validated my frontend using the below code.

Now I have value in a cookie(at_origin: "some random value") which I need to pass to invoke this auth_status api. In react, I did the following and it works.

```
export const userAuthStatus = async () => {
let authStatus = [];
 authStatus = axios.post('https://../auth_status', { resources: [{ classpath: 'test }] },
  { withCredentials: true }).then(response => response.data.user);

 return authStatus;
};
```

From react(front end) code, I am invoking backend and I need to pass the aforementioned cookie to check the auth status. I need to set the cookies(I only need the "at_origin" key-value) as X-auth before calling the auth_status from springboot(backend).

I am passing all the cookie values from the front-end to the backend in the following way.

```
try {
  const url = `https://backend api url`;
  const res = await axios.get(url, { withCredentials: true }).then(res => res);
  return res;
} catch (error) {
  console.log(error);
}
```

But I am not sure that how will I get the value (at_origin) in the backend.
Can I please get some help!

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is using it in a controller with the `@CookieValue` annotation:

```java
@RequestMapping("/hello")
public String hello(@CookieValue("foo") String fooCookie) {
    // ...
}
```

Otherwise, you can get it from the servlet request using Spring `org.springframework.web.util.WebUtils`

```java
WebUtils.getCookie(HttpServletRequest request, String cookieName)
```